# Does CF provide any support for SSO applications?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Just wanted to understand if CF provides any support for SSO applications? If yes then how?

Answer (score 5):

One of the use cases supported by the UAA is SSO.  From the [CF.org blog](http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/07/24/high-level-features-of-the-uaa/):

Because it is centralized, the UAA can provide a Single Sign On (SSO) service for applications in the Cloud Foundry platform. The cloudfoundry.com platform has several UI components and where they need to be secure they delegate to the UAA for authentication. Examples are the support site and the Micro Cloud Foundry site. (There are no other components in the core Cloud Foundry open source platform that have a UI, so it’s not really necessary to have an SSO feature until you grow the platform beyond the core use cases.)

The UI components that need SSO use the /userinfo endpoint in the UAA, which is just a regular OAuth2 protected resource (an example of the UAA acting as a Resource Server).

Comment: We've been using the CF UAA as an OAuth2 SSO (like "Connect as Facebook") for internal applications. UAA behaves like any oauth2 provider. If you look in the vcap-services repository there is an oauth2 service - this allows you to create/bind a CF oauth2 client app to the UAA oauth2 provider.